# Error with Cloud_viewer Example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cloud, point, point-cloud-library

I am new with PCL library I am trying to compile a simple example.

```
    #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

int user_data;

void 
viewerOneOff (pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer& viewer)
{
    viewer.setBackgroundColor (1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
    pcl::PointXYZ o;
    o.x = 1.0;
    o.y = 0;
    o.z = 0;
    viewer.addSphere (o, 0.25, "sphere", 0);
    std::cout << "i only run once" << std::endl;

}

void 
viewerPsycho (pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer& viewer)
{
    static unsigned count = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Once per viewer loop: " << count++;
    viewer.removeShape ("text", 0);
    viewer.addText (ss.str(), 200, 300, "text", 0);

    //FIXME: possible race condition here:
    user_data++;
}

int 
main ()
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
   // pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("my_point_cloud.pcd", *cloud);

    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
    //////////////////

    //////////////////

    //blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
    viewer.showCloud(cloud);

    //use the following functions to get access to the underlying more advanced/powerful
    //PCLVisualizer

    //This will only get called once
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThreadOnce (viewerOneOff);


    //This will get called once per visualization iteration
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThread (viewerPsycho);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
    //you can also do cool processing here
    //FIXME: Note that this is running in a separate thread from viewerPsycho
    //and you should guard against race conditions yourself...
    user_data++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug it the next error appeared:

```
Debug error. Abort() has been called.
```

And in the console appered:

```
Asserion failed, mlf_ >=minimun_max_loas factor, file C:\dev\boost_1_55_0\boost\unordered\detail\table.hpp, line 323
```

Help please

Comment: Seems to be a problem with visual studio/windows or your environment. On my Ubuntu it runs flawless. Any errors/warning while compiling? When the debug error is the next, which one is the first?

Comment: I think you are right. It's time to change windows for Linux

Comment: i am in a similar situation. I was able to build the exe for an custom built cloud application using the pcl library. But on invoking the .exe application it fails with abort call. Are you still at the same error ?

Answer (score 0):

The "cloud" is a pointer type. Need pass in what it points to as:

```
viewer.showCloud(*cloud);
```

Comment: This is wrong answer, the code from the question is directly taken from pcl tutorial  http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php As can be seen in http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_cloud_viewer.html#a845aa739fa2ed4c3e57a07e762a48c2b, the showCloud takes a pointer type, so you don't need to do what the answer suggested